# Не вызывается @dp.message_handlers()

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

суть проблемы такова, учусь делать ботов на aiogram и первая же проблема случилась с

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\pythonPROJECTS\lessonsPython\uchuPYTHON.py", line 8, in
@dp.message_handlers()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Dispatcher' object has no attri`введите сюда код`bute 'message_handlers'. Did you mean: 'message_handler'?

не понимая что да как пришел сюда за ответом.

Вот весь код:

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types

TOKEN_API = '5939705749:AA***********NTnkMxw2VMvg' # token API
bot = Bot(TOKEN_API)
dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
await message.answer(text=message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
dp.start_polling(bot)
```

Comment: Какая версия айограм установлена?

Comment: А что с отступами случилось? Где они?

Comment: отступы есть просто когда вставлял удалил, версия айограмма последняя на данный момент

Comment: Используйте @dp.message()

Comment: спасибо огромное, помогло)